# how to write a recursive trickleUp method for a heap in java?

Tags: java, recursion, heap

//Here is a trickleup method for a heap, I need assistant writing recursive method for trickleup, in java

```
public void trickleUp(int index){       
        int parent=(index-1)/2;
        Node bottom=heapArray[index];
        while(index>0 && heapArray[parent].getKey()>bottom.getKey()){
            heapArray[index]=heapArray[parent];
            index=parent;
            parent=(parent-1)/2;             

        }   
        heapArray[index]=bottom;

    }
```

Comment: Please read: [How to ask for programming help?](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-ask-for-programming-help/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void trickleUp(int index, Node bottom){       
        int parent=(index-1)/2;
        if(index>0 && heapArray[parent].getKey()>bottom.getKey()){
            heapArray[index]=heapArray[parent];          
            trickleUp(parent, bottom);
        }   
        else{
          heapArray[index]=bottom;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you !I was told to keep the interface of the method the same ! so I tried another method which will work but needs and other swap method !

Answer (score 1):

```
public void trickleUp(int index){
   int parent = (index-1) / 2;
   Node bottom = heapArray[index];

   if(index>0 && heapArray[parent].getKey()>bottom.getKey()){

      swap(index, parent);
      trickleUp(parent);
   }
}
```